# Using a function as a parameter in C

Tags: c, function

I am trying to use a function as a parameter for another function. I want to get different computations depending on the function I pass. I tried implementing this by writing this program:
 http://pastebin.com/CJfFarVa

Code:

 The problem is I get this error over and over again:

```
trapeze.c:14:8: error: conflicting types for ‘exp2’
double exp2(int number);

trapeze.c: In function ‘main’:
trapeze.c:28:35: error: expected expression before ‘int’
exp_2 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp2(int x));
                               ^
trapeze.c:29:35: error: expected expression before ‘int’
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1(int x));
                               ^
trapeze.c: At top level: 
trapeze.c:58:8: error: conflicting types for ‘exp2’
double exp2(int number)
```

**Note:** I do not want to use pointers to functions.
Sorry if this is an easy question.

Comment: Please include the code in your question, some people, like me, may not be able to access http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Sorry, no can do. The only way to pass functions around is by passing pointers to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

prototype

```
double trapeze(int a, int b, double n, double (*f)(int x));
```

call

```
exp_2 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp2);//exp2 : used c99
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1);
```

Comment: @Andy It is of passing the function is that received by the function pointer in C.

Comment: But don't I have to change the body of `trapeze` in this case? Because now I have a pointer to a function.

Comment: @Andy I think that there is no need to change the contents. (to be changed is the name of the `exp2`)

Answer (score 3):

C is not a functional programming language, which means function is not a first-class object, therefore, you cannot pass function as argument of other functions, you **have to** use pointer to function.

Comment: A function name can be used where a pointer to a function is expected.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, but that function name is acting as a pointer to function, not function itself.

Answer (score 3):

Change the call to `trapeze`:

```
exp_2 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp2);
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1(int x));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^---
```

This line is going to execute `exp1()`, then pass its return value as an argument to `trapeze`. You can't declare variables in a function call like that. Declaring argument types is something done in function definitions, not in function CALLs.

```
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1(x));
```

would be fine.

Comment: But I'm not trying to evaluate `exp1(x)`, I'm just trying to tell `trapeze` to use `exp1(x)` as the function to make the calculations in the body of `trapeze`.

Comment: Exactly. You CAN'T do that in C. It's not a functional language. C can only ever EXECUTE a function call when you use it like that. And since your function call syntax is invalid, you get your error message. Do what you want you have to pass in a poniter to the exp1 function. That's your ONLY option. If you want functional programming like that, then don't use C

Comment: @MarcB sorry for my question.I understand what you're saying. Since C is compiled I can not just call functions like that.I understand now. Thanks for your explanations.

Comment: @Andy It is not because C is compiled, it is because C **is not functional**.

Comment: @leeduhem That's exactly what I was trying to say,but I was not articulate enough to say it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to call:

```
exp_1 = trapeze(0, 1, n, exp1);
```

That way `trapeze()` gets the pointer to `exp1()` to call, not the result of calling `exp1` on some random argument.